# setState fire after setTimeout to clear component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with my code? I want to clear the error msg base on a duration. But it did not, I wonder what is wrong.

```
export default class MyError extends Component {
  state = {
    error: ''
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if(nextProps.error.msg !== prevState.error.msg){
      return {
        error: nextProps.error
      }
    }
    return null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({
        error: {}
      })
    },this.state.error.duration)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return <div>{this.state.error.msg}</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: there's no `duration` in the `state` object

Comment: what is `this.state.error.duration` ?

Comment: @Taki even though there is no duration,it will be called in next event loop,so should be clear the message

Comment: @Yunyi https://codesandbox.io/s/kx50zpmv8r its working fine for me

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your use-case with this component?  Seems a bit excessive saving props to state for what essentially amounts to an error message in a div.  (I.E. is this just a proof of concept type thing?)

Also, react will complain about setting state on an unmounted component should your `MyError` component ever unmount while an active setTimeout is alive... want to cancel those in the componentWillUnmount lifecycle function.

Comment: @DrewReese a popup alert where it shows a popup component?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN your codesanbox is broken, what are you trying to show?

Comment: @YunyiChang like a modal?  Or just an "alert" area somewhere on the page?

Comment: @DrewReese like an alert. `<Alert error={{msg: 'alert msg', duration_to_dismiss: 1000}}` it's a very common usage

Comment: @YunyiChang codesandbox is not broken.Showing your code working fine

Answer (score 0):

Set an initial time duration,

```
state = {
    error: {duration:1000}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your state object is wrong i.e you are using **state.error** as an object in render and in componentDidMount but you **declared as a String type**.

> Please check below example for more details.

```
export default class MyError extends Component {
    state = {
        error: {
            duration: 10,
            msg: ""
        }
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.error.msg !== prevState.error.msg) {
            return {
                error: nextProps.error
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState((state) => ({ error: { msg: null, duration: state.error.duration } }));
        }, this.state.error.duration)
    }

    render() {
        const {msg} = this.state.error;
        return <div> {msg} </div>
    }
}
```